# Diagrams for System Requirements

Tags: requirements, diagrams

User requirements are considered high-level functional or non-functional requirements have to be understandable by end-users and customers who may not have a technical background. We can use diagrams like use case diagrams to help with illustration of user requirements.

System requirements are more detailed requirements (both functional and non-functional) and may include more technical information. Question is, are there any specific diagrams/models that may be used for system requirements?

Comment: Please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if a use case diagram is a way to illustrate user requirements. They can be used to show the relationship between actors (who may be users) and use cases, but don't capture a lot of information associated with requirements. Use case diagrams also don't capture non-functional requirements or quality attributes of systems.

That said, there are good ways to visually model requirements:

- Business Objectives Models and Objective Chains to trace from business problems to objectives to product features.
- Feature Trees to show relationships between features in a system.
- Organizational Charts to show how users and other stakeholders fit into a broader organizational structure.
- Process flowcharts to show the business processes supported by a system. This could include lightweight flowcharts as well as more formalized business process modeling using BPMN.
- Data flow diagrams to show how data enters and exits a system, along with operations on the data during processing.
- User interface flows to show how users may navigate through different screens in an application. Can be enhanced with wireframes and mockups as the user interface is further designed and implemented.
- Roles and Permissions Matrix to define user roles in a system and what permissions each role should have with respect to various operations enabled by the system.
- Ecosystem Map to show how the system interacts with related systems. It may also be used to show subsystems within the system under design and turn into more of a design model.
- Decision Tables or Decision Trees to capture business rules, conditions, and allowed outcomes.
- State Tables or State Diagrams to capture valid states for the system and what stimuli trigger changes in state.

[Joy Beatty and Anthony Chen's Visual Models for Software Requirements](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667721) go into details on these and other types of models.

One thing that stands out is that some of these requirement models may seem like design artifacts as well. There's quite a bit of iteration between user requirements, system requirements, and system design and implementation. The biggest difference is the level of abstraction. Often, technical decisions influence the specifics of how the user requirements are modeled in the system.